SSIS, how to fetch data from a source of MySQL on AWS RDS
We have an ETL (SSIS package) that fetches data from MySQL database. The source, data warehouse, and the SSIS package are all running on-premises.
However, the source MySQL database recently moved to AWS, while the data warehouse and SSIS package are still on-premises. So we need to make adaptive changes to the SSIS package.
We have set up the following resources:

aws_access_key_id
aws_secret_access_key
role_arn

And with AWS CLI, we are able to login to a base station server in AWS and login to the RDS by command mysql -h xxx ... -p.
We wonder how to make it work with SSIS.
